# Azure Functions with java - How to get the logs written within the function?

Tags: java, azure, azure-functions, azure-java-sdk

I've deployed a queue triggered azure function with Java in Azure. I've added `logback-classic` and `lombok` in `pom.xml` for logging.
But the logs are not displayed on the function's `monitor > invocation details` or the `log-streaming service` in portal.
But I could see the logs written with `context.getLogger()`. The logs writter with logback logger is not visible. Please let me know how to check my logs in function invocation.

Following is the queue triggerred azure function handle

```
public class QueueHandlerFunction {

  @FunctionName("queuetriggertest")
  public void queueMessageHandler(@QueueTrigger(name = "msg",
      queueName = "my-test-queue", connection = "MyQStorage") final String payload,
      final ExecutionContext context) {

    //Logs with this logger is visible
    context.getLogger().info("Received Message From my-test-queue : " + payload);
    
    MySampleService.handleQueueMessage(payload);
  }
}
```

Following is the `MySampleService` class with lombok logger

```
@Slf4j
public class MySampleService {

  public static void handleQueueMessage(final String payload) {

    log.info("<<<<<<<<<<<< INSIDE THE SERVICE HANDLE >>>>>>>>>>>>");
    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(payload)) {
        log.info("Received Payload : {}", payload); //This log not available
        // TODO Work with incoming payload
    } else {
      log.info("Message payload is Blank."); //This log not available
    }
  }

}
```

Following is he `logback.xml` placed in the resources folder of the maven project.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xml>
<configuration>
   <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
      <encoder>
         <pattern>%d{E MMM dd yyyy hh:mm:ss a} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36}
                - %msg%n</pattern>
      </encoder>
   </appender>
   
   <logger name="com.howayig.test" level="INFO" />
   <root level="INFO">
      <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
   </root>
</configuration>
```

And I've the following dependencies in the `pom.xml`

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure.functions</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-functions-java-library</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.20</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

**EDIT**: Attached portal screenshot for the function invocation logs...

[image: Attached portal screenshot for the function invocation logs]

**EDIT 2**: Added screenshots of local execution and deployed one in portal.

- Logs in command prompt when is executed locally
  [image: Command prompt when executed the function locally]
- Live streaming console service of the function from the portal for a new message in queue
  [image: Portal Console with live streaming]
- Invocation details of the function from the portal for a new message in queue
  [image: Portal Invocation details]

Comment: Does that mean `appInsights` is the only way by which I can get the invocation logs? The functionality is already implemented and is using `logback` to write logs.
I'm trying to execute the same functionality with Azure functions. I would like to see the logs in invocation details. see image attached. But it only shows the context logger logs there. Should I use this context logger wherever I have to log something? You can see the log statements are in a different class. Similarly there are more logs in the execution flow. I've to see them. Does it blocks the log entries from other loggers?

Comment: another words, it's working locally, but when you deploy to azure it does not work?

Comment: also you keep referring to _invocation_ logs. what does invocation mean?

Comment: Invocation refers to the act of invoking a method. It's plain english.

Comment: The invocation means the function gets executed whenever a new message is added to the queue(Its a queue triggered function). I pack the function with command `mvn clean package`. The command `mvn azure-functions:run` is used to run it locally. `mvn azure-functions:deploy` is used to deploy it. You can see that the statement _<<<<<<<<<<<< INSIDE THE SERVICE HANDLE >>>>>>>>>>>>_ is visible when its run locally. But the log statements in the class `MySampleService` is not available when its deployed in portal (not available in log streaming or invocation details).

Answer (score 3):

None of the logging framework works other than **java.util.logging** till this date.

I have tried with log4j2, but logs don't come up in invocations details **and hence they don't show up in Application Insights query** either.

But Log4j2 logs appear under **"Log stream"** section of any of your Functions Apps. But again, that's not really helpful.

If you have already built-in application with some other logging framework, then either you need to change all of your logging to **java.util.logging** or do below.

Create below 2 custom classes in a separate maven module and include that to all of your function modules. **Have same package name as the framework that you are using. In my case its "org.apache.logging.log4j"**

They are not perfectly built custom classes. But this works.

### LogManager.java

```
package org.apache.logging.log4j;

public class LogManager {

    static Logger logger = new Logger();

    public static Logger getLogger() {
        return logger;
    }

    public static void setLogger(Logger logger1) {
        logger = logger1;
    }

    public static Logger getLogger(Class<?> class1) {
        return logger;
    }

    public static Logger getLogger(String name) {
        return logger;
    }
}
```

### Logger.java

```
package org.apache.logging.log4j;

import java.util.logging.Level;

public class Logger {

    private java.util.logging.Logger logger;

    public void setLogger(java.util.logging.Logger logger) {
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    public void debug(Object... obj) {
        printLog(obj, Level.FINE);
    }

    public void info(Object... obj) {
        printLog(obj, Level.INFO);
    }

    public void error(Object... obj) {
        printLog(obj, Level.SEVERE);
    }

    public void log(Object level, Object... obj) {
        printLog(obj, Level.FINEST);
    }

    public void warn(Object... obj) {
        printLog(obj, Level.WARNING);
    }

    private void printLog(Object[] obj, Level level) {
        if (obj != null) {

            String logString = obj[0] != null ? obj[0].toString() : "";

            if (obj.length > 1) {
                for (int i = 1; i < obj.length; i++) {
                    if (obj[i] != null) {
                        logString = logString.replaceFirst("\\{}", obj[i].toString());
                    }
                }                   
            }
            logger.log(level, logString);
        }
    }
}
```

**Then you can set your custom logger using Azure's Execution Context.**

```
// LOG var Global to class    
private final Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger(BgdInfoAnalyticsHandler.class);

@FunctionName("func-name-fn")
    public void run(
            @ServiceBusQueueTrigger(name = "TriggerName", queueName = "sbq-use-queue-name", connection = "AzureWebJobsServiceBus") String input,
            ExecutionContext context) {
        LOG.setLogger(context.getLogger());
        LogManager.setLogger(LOG);
        String fnInput = HostServiceUtil.getBlobData(input);
        LOG.info("fnInput : {} ", fnInput);
        invokeService(fnInput);
    }
```

Once this Logger is initiated/set in the entry point of your run method with Azure's ExecutionContext logger. You get this logger from any other class by doing **LogManager.getLogger** (Custom Class) as it is static.

**Note:** [Static vars are being shared by different invocations or functions (if they resides in same function app)](https://markheath.net/post/sharing-state-between-azure-functions)

Then you can do query in Application Insights as below:

```
union traces
| union exceptions | union requests
// | where timestamp > ago(2d)
// | where cloud_RoleName =~ 'fun-use-function-app-name' and operation_Name =~ 'function-name-fn' //and operation_Id =~ "7303edd79433b0468f934c80a88e5f77"
// | where innermostMessage contains "Exception" or message contains "Exception"
| project timestamp, message = iff(message != '', message, 
    iff(innermostMessage != '', innermostMessage, customDimensions.['prop__{OriginalFormat}'])), logLevel = customDimensions.['LogLevel']
    , operation_Name, operation_Id, cloud_RoleName, invocationId=customDimensions['InvocationId']
| order by timestamp asc
| take 3000
```

**You can also see Failure/Exception under: ApplicationInsights > Investigate section > Failures**

Comment: This is no longer true. AppInsights supports SLF4J out of the box. Check: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71203259/894565

Answer (score 2):

It's now available via [distributed tracing](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-java-worker/wiki/Distributed-Tracing-for-Java-Azure-Functions). You can view richer data from your function applications pertaining to the following [requests, dependencies, logs and metrics.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/java-in-process-agent#autocollected-requests-dependencies-logs-and-metrics)

All you need is:

1. Add dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>applicationinsights-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.0</version>
  </dependency>
```

2. Create a configuration file named **ApplicationInsights.json** with the following content:

```
{
  "instrumentationSettings": {
    "connectionString": "InstrumentationKey=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
  }
}
```

3. Create a TelemetryClient:

```
private static final TelemetryClient telemetryClient = new TelemetryClient();
```

4. Use it

```
  telemetryClient.trackTrace(message, SeverityLevel.Warning, properties);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Updated in 2022**

Application Insights agent supports SLF4j logs (for log4j2, logback, and jul) out of the box. Quoting from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/java-standalone-config#auto-collected-logging

> Log4j, Logback, and java.util.logging are auto-instrumented, and
> logging performed via these logging frameworks is auto-collected.
> Logging is only captured if it first meets the level that is
> configured for the logging framework, and second, also meets the level
> that is configured for Application Insights.

For more details, refer to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71203259/894565

Answer (score -1):

You need to use Kudu.

Get the URL for the application, if your application URL is xxxxxxx.azurewebsites.net, then input xxxxxxx.scm.azurewebsites.net to see the logs.