# Azure function App logs into App Insights using slf4j

Tags: azure, azure-functions, spring-cloud-function, appinsights

Implemented Azure Function App with Spring Cloud Functions. App Insights instrumentation key configured in App Settings "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY": .
I'm using lombok annotation @Slf4j for logging the messages, but I can't see them in App insights. App insights is capturing only log which written using ExecutionContext log.
Can any one give me a reference on how to log the messages in App Insights using slf4j.

Comment: Have you seen this - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/sdk/logging-overview

Answer (score 1):

If you are using AppInsights 2.x, you can use `applicationinsights-logging-logback` or `applicationinsights-logging-log4j2` libraries to enable logging. Please read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/java-2x-trace-logs) to learn more about enabling logs.

```xml
    <!-- Logback -->
    <dependencies>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
          <artifactId>applicationinsights-logging-logback</artifactId>
          <version>[2.0,)</version>
       </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <!-- Log4J 2.0 -->
    <dependencies>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
          <artifactId>applicationinsights-logging-log4j2</artifactId>
          <version>[2.0,)</version>
       </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

If you are using AppInsights 3.x, you can [configure the agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/status-monitor-v2-overview)  which will automatically export logs to App Insights.

There's also a [preview feature in Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/monitor-functions#how-to-enable-distributed-tracing-for-java-function-apps) to enable distributed tracing that can be enabled from the Azure portal.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated in 2022**

Application Insights agent supports SLF4j logs (for log4j2, logback, and jul) out of the box. Quoting from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/java-standalone-config#auto-collected-logging

> Log4j, Logback, and java.util.logging are auto-instrumented, and
> logging performed via these logging frameworks is auto-collected.
> Logging is only captured if it first meets the level that is
> configured for the logging framework, and second, also meets the level
> that is configured for Application Insights.

It is now pretty straight-forward:

1. Application Insights needs to be enabled for your azure function
2. Add the following in azure function configurations. More details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/monitor-functions):

```
ApplicationInsightsAgent_EXTENSION_VERSION=~3
```

3. Just like any other project add the logback dependency

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.10</version>
        </dependency>
```

and a sample logback.xml

3. Finally within your azure function, log using the SLF4j API:

```
    LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass()).info("====================SLF4j Logger=======================");
```

With the above done, you should be able to view the logs in App Insights

```
traces
| order by timestamp desc 
| limit 3000
```

`severity` column represents the log level. (3 = Error. 1 = Information)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Answering My own question. Tried a couple of above approaches, nothing worked. Finally passed the ExecutionContext from handler to remaining services through method call.

Answer (score 0):

When using that logger, always pass the Throwable as part of the error so that app insights can collect it and show you the throwables metadata:

```
log.error(String.format("Message {}", message), e);
```

If you convert the e to a string, that wont happen.  You'll just get a bare bones log message.